# Changing skin on jquery msdropdown plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm using the Jquery plugin msdropdown http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown but am confused on how to change the skin. By default it uses the dd skin in the msdropdown/dd.css file. There is also a second skin called dd2, which is more desirable for my site.

```
<select style="width:150px" name="webmenu" id="webmenu" onchange= "openprompt()">
        <option value="selectvalue">Select...</option>
    <option value="augustanacollege" title="icons/augustanacollege.gif">Augustana College </option>
    <option value="aurorauniversity " title="icons/aurorauniversity.gif">Aurora University</option>
  </select>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
try {
$("body select").msDropDown();
} catch(e) {
alert(e.message);
}
});
</script>

<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        try {
        $("#webmenu").msDropDown();
    }
    });
</script>
```

It's saying to add the following code to change the skin:

```
<code>$("#comboboxid").msDropDown({mainCSS:'dd2'}); //dd2 is your main CSS
```

So would #comboboxid equal my dropdown box id of #webmenu? Also, is mainCSS just my dd.css file? If so, do I need to specify the location like so: msdropdown/dd.css?

Comment: Obviously I've already tried this if I'm asking the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using code you mentioned you can specify css class for the dropdown you've created:

```
$("#webmenu").msDropDown({mainCSS:'dd2'});
```

In your `dd.css` file you can find default styles. Copy them, modify like you want and call main css class something different than `dd` and assign it to property in sample.

Also you can leave how it is and just update styles in `dd.css` to match you requirements.

Important note:

> Please don't change "display, float and overflow" properties.

Comment: Hi Samich, thank you for your reply. So is "body select" a property? Is that what I need to replace mainCSS with? What I'm also confused about is how to invoke the skin.

Comment: In this case invoking the skin is just changing css class. So you need to replace your `$("#webmenu").msDropDown();` string with from the sample one.